# How to Lay Out C# Windows Forms Correctly, and allow for Scaling?

Tags: c#, layout, scaling

I am one week into learning C#, and I am currently working on a large application, as my C/C++ and Python knowledge comes into play - one problem here, however: C, C++ and Python don't have a GUI for creating GUIs.

I noticed that simply placing controls on a window won't work, and instead they need to be layed out in GroupBox-es and TableLayoutPanel(s) - and TabControl(s).

My aim is to achieve scaling, so at any size the program will look similar (this is very important for this program specifically).

At the moment, resizing makes my whole program flicker, and it doesn't even work properly.

I managed to sort-of do this in a previous program, however I've lost it at this point and have no idea what I'm doing.

Here are a few screenshots of my current work:
https://justpaste.it/119kb (screenshot links pasted on this website, as StackOverflow is not letting me put more than 2 links or images)

As you can see, it doesn't scale properly.

(as bad as it may look, I'm working on it - I haven't released the first version yet, and I will definitely revamp the whole program before release, just trying things out here)

Could someone enlighten me with tips on how to scale properly or inform me of something I'm not using?

Comment: I think since you are new to C# that instead of picking up Windows Forms you should instead learn WPF, that will give you all the power and flexibility you need to manage complex layouts and deal with scaling etc. Windows Forms is out dated technology at this point so I wouldn't take much time to learn it unless you need to support legacy applications.

Comment: Wow I didn't realise. As good as WPF looks, however, the code doesn't make sense to me. All I see is HTML and I don't understand it.

Comment: Coming from Windows Forms myself I felt exactly the same way! The XAML part is just the UI layer all your C# code exists behind the scenes with the UI updated via data binding which to me still feels like magic. It's definitely a completely different approach that requires a different thought process but the benefits of WPF + MVVM pattern are immense and well worth it. Personally I'll never go back to Windows Forms.

Comment: Thanks man. That was perhaps the answer I was looking for. On a second thought, WPF is really appealing and I will definitely be learning some of that. Thanks for the insight, I would have never noticed WPF. When making a new project, I tend to overlook all the options available and just click on the one I need - I guess I treat the other ones as too advanced or unnecessary.